# Реализация видео стены на php

Tags: php, jquery, видео, videoview

Подскажите элемент управления\технологию для реализации следующего функционала на php-странице:
Экран монитора разделен на 2 горизонтальных блока. В 1-ом задана разметка экранов мониторов видео стены, во 2-ом список виджетов для отображения на видео стене.
Пользователь может перетаскивать виджет на какой-то 1 монитор видео стены или, кликнув на виджете из списка, иметь возможность выделить мониторы, на которых он будет отображаться. После помещения на видео стену виджет должен проигрывать видео в выбранных "мониторах" (т.е. выбранной области 1-ого блока с разметкой видео стены) 
Предполагаю использовать jQuery, но выслушаю любое мнение. Какой элемент управления лучше всего подойдет для реализации подобного функционала, в-первую очередь интересуют готовые решения (если имеются).

Comment: react с redux и все будет шикарно :)

Comment: слишком много видео стены, хотя если добавить ещё немного видео стены то становится уже фиолетово на видео стену даже не обращаешь внимание, остается сконцентрироваться только на стене с видео или по другому видео стене. Возможно видео стену стоит вынести в отдельную функцию.

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich в реакте это будет компонент, поэтому не имеет значения сколько их будет :D

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Я уже представляю этот код =)

Comment: Переспрошу, пока есть возможность. Если из вышеперечисленного убрать требование отображения видео (вместо этого просто текст с его названием), а добавить требования масштабируемости. Т.е. после установки виджета, можно растянуть его или сузить. Предложенные библиотеки все еще будут актуальны или уже избыточны?

Comment: @Павел Как т.к. ты на реакте пишешь компонентно, расширяемость может быть овер бесконечной. Главное понять концепт (вместе с flux (redux))

Comment: Верю, но у меня есть еще ограничение времени\затрат. Прохожу стажировку.

Comment: По моему очевидно что если вы хотите получить ответ на вопрос, начните с формулировки вопроса, в ней содержится 60% ответа. Пример: Сколько лет одиннадцатилетнему мальчику.